# What is correct Route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I created language switcher but I have problem when is subpage. My route:

```
Route::post('/language', array(
    'Middleware' => 'LanguageSwitcher',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@index'
));
```

Works fine for example:

```
http://localhost:8000/
http://localhost:8000/gallery
```

but not for;

```
http://localhost:8000/gallery/bodnar
```

then I recaive

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

If I set:

```
Route::post('/gallery/language', array(
    'Middleware' => 'LanguageSwitcher',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@index'
));
```

works for

```
http://localhost:8000/gallery/bodnar
```

but not for

```
http://localhost:8000/
http://localhost:8000/gallery
```

What is the correct Route::post to be universal?

my LanguageSwitcher.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

use App;
use Lang;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

class LanguageSwitcher {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        App::setLocale(Session::has('locale') ? Session::get('locale') : Config::get('app.locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "universal"? Do you want it to be able to handle ALL POST requests or only those 3 you mentioned? (/, /gallery, /gallery/bodnar)? And how is it possible that "/gallery/language" matches "/gallery/bodnar"?

Comment: I mean to be routed always - ALL POST. When I open subpage /gallery/bodnar and than try to switch language or when I open /gallery. Maybe I should use something like this: Route::post('/{name?}/language' ? But that not works and I don't know whitch syntax is correct.

Comment: I have jus used both Route:---`Route::post('/language', array(
    'Middleware' => 'LanguageSwitcher',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@index'
));

Route::post('/{name}/language', array(
    'Middleware' => 'LanguageSwitcher',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@index'
));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you need.

With your language switcher, I'm going to assume it's not an absolute path?

Perhaps use your first example:

```
Route::post('/language', array(
    'Middleware' => 'LanguageSwitcher',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@index'
));
```

And for when calling that route use the following in blade:

```
{{ url('language') }}
```

This would prevent the directory issue.

Comment: In the view I use form and I don't know how to use yours advide. `<form id="lang-form" action="language" method="post" class="form-inline lf">
<select name="locale" id="lang" class="form-control">
<option value="en" {{ App::getLocale() == 'en' ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' }}>English</option>
<option value="pl" {{ App::getLocale() == 'pl' ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' }}>Polski</option>
</select>

                                                                {{ Form::token() }}
                                                            </form>`

Comment: Try this: (I can't seem to format it for some reason?)

    <form id="lang-form" action="{{ url('language') }}" method="post" class="form-inline lf"><select name="locale" id="lang" class="form-control"><option value="en" {{ App::getLocale() == 'en' ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' }}>English</option><option value="pl" {{ App::getLocale() == 'pl' ? 'selected = "selected"' : '' }}>Polski</option></select>{{ Form::token() }}</form>